# MS SQL combine first last name and the compare to different single value

Tags: sql-server

Try to pull first and last name from a database combine into one value, and then combine the results with a different server database. The problem being my database has first and last separate, the target database has first and last combine in one string. Basically trying to get a list from both databases matching on the full name.

```
select a.empid,
select (SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(COALESCE(a.FNAM + ' ', '') +
                                        COALESCE(a.LNAM, '')), '  ', ' '))name1,
a.Email
from [db]..[user].[table] a, [server].[db].[dbo].[tblUsers] t 
where name1 = t.Name
```

Witht he above, it just says invalid column anme1, which makes sense because it is just a result set column name. How can I make this full name value from my DB and then match it with the full name value of column t.Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select a.empid, 
    a.FNAM, a.LNAM, t.Name 
 from [db]..[user].[table] a 
    join [server].[db].[dbo].[tblUsers] t 
       on Replace(a.FNAM + a.LNAM, ' ', '') 
          = Replace(t.Name, ' ', '')
```

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for. Thanks.